# pyspark df.count() taking a very long time (or not working at all)

Tags: apache-spark, count, pyspark

I have the following code that is simply doing some joins and then outputting the data;

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.logConf', 'true')

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .appName("Generate Parameters") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")

df1 = spark.read.parquet("/location/mydata")
df1 = df1.select([c for c in df1.columns if c in ['sender','receiver','ccc,'cc','pr']])

df2 = spark.read.csv("/location/mydata2")

cond1 = [(df1.sender == df2._c1) | (df1.receiver == df2._c1)]

df3 = df1.join(broadcast(df2), cond1)
df3 = df3.select([c for c in df3.columns if c in['sender','receiver','ccc','cc','pr']])
```

`df1` is `1,862,412,799` rows and `df2` is `8679` rows

when I then call;

```
df3.count()
```

It just seems to sit there with the following

```
[Stage 33:>                                                     (0 + 200) / 200]
```

Comment: The thing is it only takes a second to count the `1,862,412,799` rows and df3 should be smaller.

Comment: There is a join operation too which makes sense  `df3 = df1.join(broadcast(df2), cond1)`.

Comment: That stage is complete. It is only the count which is taking forever to complete

Comment: It is, count() is a lazy operation. Are you running a single node cluster?

Comment: OK. How would I get to see the number of records in df3 in that case? I am running this on an edge node

Comment: Is it still stuck?

Comment: Do some reparation and try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assumptions for this answer:**

- df1 is the dataframe containing 1,862,412,799 rows.
- df2 is the dataframe containing 8679 rows.
- df1.count() returns a value quickly (as per your comment)

There may be three areas where the slowdown is occurring:

**The imbalance of data sizes (1,862,412,799 vs 8679):**

Although spark is amazing at handling large quantities of data, it doesn't deal well with very small sets. If not specifically set, Spark attempts to partition your data into multiple parts and on small files this can be excessively high in comparison to the actual amount of data each part has. I recommend trying to use the following and see if it improves speed.

```
df2 = spark.read.csv("/location/mydata2")
df2 = df2.repartition(2)
```

Note: The number 2 here is just an estimated number, based on how many partitions would suit the amount of rows that are in that set.

**Broadcast Cost:**

The delay in the count may be due to the actual broadcast step. Your data is being saved and copied to every node within your cluster before the join, this all happening together once count() is called. Depending on your infrastructure, this could take some time. If the above repartition doesn't work, try removing the broadcast call. If that ends up being the delay, it may be good to confirm that there are no bottlenecks within your cluster or if it's necessary.

**Unexpected Merge Explosion**

I do not imply that this is an issue, but it is always good to check that the merge condition you have set is not creating unexpected duplicates. It is a possibility that this may be happening and creating the slow down you are experiencing when actioning the processing of df3.

Comment: Thanks! I had an unexpected Merge Explosion.